# vuejs creating onclick event from js method DOM

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events

In my Vue CLI component, I'm populating a row table dynamically

i.e. inside my `methods`:

```
add_row() {
        var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
        var new_country = document.getElementById("new_country").value;
        var new_age = document.getElementById("new_age").value;

        var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
        var table_len = table.rows.length - 1;
        table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML =
            "<tr id='row" +
            table_len +
            "'><td id='name_row" +
            table_len +
            "'>" +
            new_name +
            "</td><td id='country_row" +
            table_len +
            "'>" +
            new_country +
            "</td><td id='age_row" +
            table_len +
            "'>" +
            new_age +
            "</td><td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' @click=\"delete_row(" +
            table_len +
            ')"></td></tr>';

        document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("new_country").value = "";
        document.getElementById("new_age").value = "";
    }
```

This is the HTML part of the component:

```
<table
                align="center"
                cellspacing="2"
                cellpadding="5"
                id="data_table"
                border="1"
            >
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>

                <tr id="row1">
                    <td id="name_row1">Ankit</td>
                    <td id="country_row1">India</td>
                    <td id="age_row1">20</td>
                    <td>
                        <input
                            type="button"
                            value="Delete"
                            class="delete"
                            @click="delete_row('1')"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_name" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_country" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_age" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input
                            type="button"
                            class="add"
                            @click="add_row()"
                            value="Add Row"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Notice in my **add_row** function, when populating the row, I append a delete button tag and in it, pass the method **delete_row**. Clicking on this delete button should fire the method as shown below:

in my methods:

```
delete_row(no) {
        document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
    },
```

But the method is not being triggered from the delete_row function. I've confirmed that the rows are working well since my button for adding that row the add_row function fires. So my thinking is since I call the **delete_row** function from a dynamically created, there's perhaps something extra that I need to pass to my code to trigger this method?

Comment: Why bother using vue if you code like this? Now you just using plain js inside vue. Use v-models to bind your data. Use v-for to insert table data. Use 'this' reference to delete correct rows... If all this is been improved, probably your current problem wouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Can you illustrate this with code because I am a beginner with vuejs and so I used plain javascript